# What is the Eclipse equivalent of IntelliJ "Live templates"?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, intellij-idea, live-templates

I mean stuff like typing "iter" and getting a "for" loop with a choice of what variable to iterate on , typing "soutv" to generate a "System.out.println" with the "variable=" already in ...

Thanks !

Comment: By default, typing `sysout` will create a `System.out.println()` in Eclipse.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is called *Templates* and it's found under,

***Window → Preferences → Java → Editor → Templates***

[image]

The "soutv" template does not exist ("sysout" does, and it's similar), but it's easy to add. I used this pattern:

```
System.out.println("variable=" + ${cursor}${});
```

Answer (score 4):

Check under

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates
```

**Reference:**

- [Template Variables](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm)

Comment: Link seems to be outdated (shows "Topic not found"). More recent one: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm

Comment: @geisterfurz007 (nice nickname :-))
Thanks, link is updated.

Answer (score 4):

For 'soutv' particularly, I found the following pattern worked well in Eclipse:

```
System.out.println("${var} = ${cursor}" + ${var});
```

As others have mentioned, you can add this template by navigating to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates and clicking New.

The equivalent of 'iter' seems to be 'for' in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

They are called Templates.

Go to `Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates` to see a list of pre-defined templates.

For example, `sysout` is:

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

You can also create your own.